# Uploading files to REST from java side works, from python not

Tags: java, python, rest, file-upload

We are testing Saperion REST web service and everything goes okay except file upload. Everything goes ok from java side:

```
public HttpResponse insertDocument(String docId) throws IOException {

    RestClient client = new RestClient();

    byte[][] file1 = null;
    System.out.println("insertDocument: Reading attachment files to insert...");
    try {

        file1 = new byte[][]
                {

                 client.readFile("/usr/local/www/test.pdf")

                };

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("******** insertDocument catch ******");
        System.out.println("insertDocument: File not read...");
        System.out.println("insertDocument: Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        String url = SERVER + INSERT_DOCUMENT_OPERATION;
        System.out.println("insertDocument: url - " + url + "/" + docId);

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
        httpPost.setHeaders(getAuthentication());


        // META
        String str = "<query id=\"001\">" +
                "<docid>" + docId + "</docid>" +
                "<dochead>" +
                "</dochead>" +
                "<attachments count=\"" + file1.length + "\">";


        for (int i = 0; i < file1.length; i++) {
            str += "<entry><filename>" + docId + "_" + i + ".pdf" + "</filename>" +
                    "<filedata/>" +
                    "</entry>";
        }

        str += "</attachments>" +
                "</query>";

        System.out.println("insertDocument: str - " + str);

        MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity();
        entity.addPart("xmlString", new StringBody(str));

        for (byte[] file : file1)
            entity.addPart("file", new ByteArrayBody(file, "file"));

        httpPost.setEntity(entity);


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        System.out.println("insertDocument: return response ...");
        return response;

    } finally {
        httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
}
```

This, is how looks request content:

```
POST /saperion/services/rest/insertDocument HTTP/1.1
RC_USER: user
RC_USER_PASSWORD: pass
Content-Length: 8476
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=3mzL6oR0- E0dudMZ_pV3OVTE41pV4yH
Host: appdevel4.kada.lan
Connection: Keep-Alive
User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.2 (java 1.5)
--3mzL6oR0-E0dudMZ_pV3OVTE41pV4yH

Content-Disposition": "form-data; name="xmlString"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
<query id="001"><docid>55</docid><dochead></dochead><attachments     count="1"><entry><filename>55_0.pdf</filename><filedata/></entry></attachments></query>
--3mzL6oR0-E0dudMZ_pV3OVTE41pV4yH
Content-Disposition:form-data; name="file"; filename="file"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: "binary"
binary pdf content
--3mzL6oR0-E0dudMZ_pV3OVTE41pV4yH
```

Here code from python side:

```
xml="""<query id="001">
        <docid>56</docid>
        <dochead></dochead>
        <attachments count="1">
            <entry>
                <filename>56_0.pdf</filename>
                <filedata/>
            </entry>
        </attachments>
        </query>"""


url="http://appdevel4.kada.lan/saperion/services/rest/insertDocument/56"
files = {'xmlString': (None, xml, "text/plain; charset=US-ASCII", {'Content-Transfer-Encoding':'8bit'} ), 'file': ('file', open('/usr/local/www/test.pdf', 'rb'), "application/octet-stream", {'Content-Transfer-Encoding':'binary'})}
    headers={
    'Host':'appdevel4.kada.lan',
    'POST': '/saperion/services/rest/insertDocument HTTP/1.1',
    'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
    'RC_USER':'user', 
    'RC_USER_PASSWORD':'passwd'
    }
    response = requests.post("http://appdevel4.kada.lan/saperion/services/rest/insertDocument/55", files=files, headers=headers)
```

Here are content of python request:

```
POST http://appdevel4.kada.lan/saperion/services/rest/insertDocument/56
Content-Length: 8521
Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: appdevel4.kada.lan
Cookie: JSESSIONID=li0vmwnqKmtcWF2sWk06cFWG
RC_USER: user
RC_USER_PASSWORD: passwd
POST: /saperion/services/rest/insertDocument HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=477579b8a0b04c9286c7c78ce3bb72b5

--477579b8a0b04c9286c7c78ce3bb72b5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="xmlString"
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

<query id="001">
<docid>56</docid>
<dochead></dochead>
<attachments count="1">
<entry>
<filename>56_0.pdf</filename>
<filedata/>
</entry>
</attachments>
</query>

--477579b8a0b04c9286c7c78ce3bb72b5
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
PDF content
--477579b8a0b04c9286c7c78ce3bb72b5--
```

So, contents of java and python requests, practically are the same, but java uploads are successful, but python produces 404 Not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post URLs are different in Java and Python. In Java it is `/saperion/services/rest/insertDocument` while in Python it is `http://appdevel4.kada.lan/saperion/services/rest/insertDocument/56`. Make sure your requests are same before you can compare.

Comment: Thanks :) Leaving only insertDocument in Python fixed the issue.